# why my wordpress dont have toolbar like, plugin, themes and other?

Tags: plugins, themes, metabox, options, tooltip

why my wordpress dont have toolbar like, plugin, themes and other ?

thet is screenprint of my wp. [image]

Comment: You're not an administrator of the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not having correct admin privileges. However if you have the database access then you can check the which role is assigned to you... Hope it answer. If you need any help please let us know. If you think this is the cause please mark the answer as SOLVED.

Thanks..

Comment: i dont now how to check thet, can you send mi turtorial for thet ?

Comment: Thanks for accepting it as a solution. I think this will help you https://youtu.be/hgMvqZXciZ4 Please let us know if it is unclear then we will help you little more....